# Add placeholder for free text contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Hi guys I want to add placeholder for the last option checkbox. Here is my cf7 code,

`[checkbox check-question1 free_text id:question1 use_label_element class:filled-in class:other "Instagram" "Facebook" "Twitter" "Tumblr" "Path" "Lainnya:(Social Media Lain)"]`

I'm read CF7 documentation here https://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/ but nothing documentation for add free text placeholder. How to add placeholder for free text ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a placeholder to an input checkbox ? That not possible in HTML.

To add a placeholder to an input text, this is the way :
`[text your-text placeholder "Lorem"]`

Answer (score 0):

Unhappily it's not possible right now.

The text input created when **free_text** options is active has no placeholder option.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one last option to your list, like 'Other', and that will display before the free text.

[checkbox check-question1 free_text id:question1 use_label_element class:filled-in class:other "Instagram" "Facebook" "Twitter" "Tumblr" "Path" "Lainnya:(Social Media Lain)" **"Other:"**]